# Multiple checkboxes validation rules, only works when every checkbox selected

Tags: django, validation, checkbox

I have a template which goes through a queryset and creates a checkbox for each item which seems to be a validation problem. I can only submit this when I check every checkbox and I just can't seem to figure out what is wrong.

my template:

```
<form method="POST">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <fieldset>
      {% for choice in choices %}
      {{ choice.description }}
      <input type="checkbox" value="{{choice.section}}" name="sections" required="">
      {% endfor %}
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

my forms.py

```
class AddSectionForm(forms.Form):
    sections = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

### edit

Urghh, I'm an idiot, it's the `required=""` in the html checkbox object!

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer below rather than editing your quesiton.

Comment: Turns out this is only a partial answer, I fixed the problem with validation but this still fails the form.is_valid()

Comment: @Chonker: there are no `choices=...` for your `sections`...

Comment: Can you post the relevant view?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Willem, you got it!  Also needed to change the checkbox values for the primary keys.

forms.py:

```
class AddSectionForm(forms.Form):
sections = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
    required=True, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
    choices=Section.objects.all().values_list())
```

template:

```
<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<fieldset>
{% for choice in choices %}
{{ choice.description }}
<input type="checkbox" value="{{choice.pk}}" name="sections">
{% endfor %}
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your checkboxes should not have `required=""`, otherwise it is required to check these. Furthermore it is probably more elegant to use a `ModelMultipleChoiceField`:

```
class AddSectionForm(forms.Form):
    sections = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Section.objects.all(),
        required=True,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
    )
```